# Slide textview horizontal without using paging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I`m using a simple Textview in an tabbased application to display some text :) I figerd out how to change the text animated using the following code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self];

// To be a swipe, direction of touch must be horizontal and long enough.
if (fabsf(startTouchPosition.x - currentTouchPosition.x) >= HORIZ_SWIPE_DRAG_MIN &&
    fabsf(startTouchPosition.y - currentTouchPosition.y) <= VERT_SWIPE_DRAG_MAX)
{
    // It appears to be a swipe.
    if (startTouchPosition.x < currentTouchPosition.x){
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"..."];
        self.text = string;
    }
    else{
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
        //[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:[self superview] cache:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:[self superview] cache:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [[self superview] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self displayNewText];
    }
}
```

However there is now "slide transition" defined in UIViewAnimationTransition. I know about paging, but I don`t want to use this. Is there an other possibility to have an horizontal slide animation when detecting a horizontal swipe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there. Intercept `touchesMoved:withEvent` method just like in your current code and update the visible area of the UIScrollView object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don`t know what you mean with "update the visible area of the UIScrollView object." :) To what should it be updated?

Comment: [scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 160, 280, 440) animated:YES]; use this function to update the scrollview's visible rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't have to detect touches for your requirement use UIScrollView as parent view for UITextView.

```
    scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40, 320,200)];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, 200)];
```

Or if you want to animate the view you can use affine transforms.

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
        someview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Well the animation works. However I need to detect touches which have to perform a instance method from the containerviews viewcontroller. That seems to be a big problem.